# Error while importing data from csv in django

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to import data from csv into the django database.

models.py

```
class contactDetails(models.Model):
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phonenumber = models.IntegerField()
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname
```

save_form_data is project name and AppFormSaving is an app.

import.py

```
project_dir = 'K:\\PY\\save_form_data'
## project_dir = 'K:\\PY\\save_form_data\AppFormSaving'
sys.path.append(project_dir)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django

django.setup()

from AppFormSaving.models import contactDetails

data = csv.reader(open('K:\\sample.csv'), delimiter=",")

for row in data:
    if row[0] != 'firstname':
        details = contactDetails()
        details.firstname = row[0]
        details.lastname = row[1]
        details.phonenumber = row[2]
        details.email = row[3]

        details.save()
```

when I run import.py

```
    K:\PY\save_form_data>python import.py
```

I get an error below,

```
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __geta
ttr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup

    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init
__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igKeXLDMSqU) tutorial.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you actually have a settings.py file in your project/folder ?

Comment: In project/app_folder? No.
I am just wondering how come it will have settings. py file(It is an app)?
I tried copying it from the main project folder, no luck.

Comment: He has it in the project/thesite/ folder: https://youtu.be/igKeXLDMSqU?t=2m35s

Comment: When you see "No module named 'X'", that is almost always something in your settings.py file.  Did you accidentally put 'settings' in your setings.py file?

Comment: @Timm Simpkins  Nope.

Comment: an often seen mistake. The best way to load CSV is using the functionality provide by the database. not with django, laravel, hibernate etc etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing a code to populate database using python (Django)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927925/optimizing-a-code-to-populate-database-using-python-django)